# Why doesn't multiple `\n` characters end up in the standard input stream?

Tags: c, newline, stdin, scanf

This question has always bugged me. Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

  char one,mid,final;
  int num;

  printf("Enter the first character:\n");
  scanf("%c",&one);

  printf("Enter any integer:\n");
  scanf("%d",&num);

  printf("Enter the middle character:\n");
  scanf("%c",&mid);

  printf("Enter the final character:\n");
  scanf("%c",&final);

  printf("You have entered\n");
  printf("\"%c\" and \"%d\" and \"%c\" and \"%c\"\n",one,num,mid,final);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And suppose the input is

```
A\n
34\n
B\n
```

Here,

The first `scanf` gets `A` and leaves the `\n` in the `stdin`.
The 2<sup>nd</sup> one does not comsume the `\n` as `%d` skips them and thus,gets 34. This `scanf` also leaves the `\n` character in the `stdin`.
The 3<sup>rd</sup> `scanf` gets the `\n` left over by the second `scanf`.
The 4<sup>th</sup> `scanf` gets `B` and again,leaves the `\n` in the `stdin`.

My question is: Why doesn't the last `scanf` consume the `\n` character left over by the first `scanf`?

Comment: The second scanf call *does* consume the `\n` from the first call. It just discards it, and keeps reading.

Comment: So the `%d` gobbles up all white-space characters before scanning an integer?

Comment: @mafso, `scanf` in the body of the loop flushes the `stdin` in case the second `scanf` failed. That `scanf` isn't the 1st,2nd,3rd or 4th `scanf`. This might seem confusing for future readers so I've removed it.

Comment: That's an improvement, thanks. But still: Why _should_ the 4th `scanf` consume what the _first_ one left inside the input stream?

Comment: @mafso, Well,I didn't know that the second one "consumes" the `\n`.

Comment: Ah OK, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @CoolGuy: Yes, the `%d` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to consume and ignore any leading whitespace, including the newline character.  In fact, the only conversion spoecifiers that *don't* tell `scanf` to consume leading whitespace are the `%c` and `%[` conversion specifiers.  Note that a blank space in the format string also consumes whitespace, so you can avoid your problem by writing `scanf( " %c", &c );` (note blank space before `%c`).

Comment: @JohnBode Also `"%n"`  "Input white-space characters ... are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier" C11dr §7.21.6.2 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A skipped character is not "left" in the stream. The input stream can only be read once and in one direction,<sup>1</sup> so once a character is skipped, it's *gone.*

<sub><sup>1</sup> without extra fanciness, such as buffering</sub>

Comment: Ah thanks for clearing my doubt. Your answer is really helpful !

Comment: @Matt Ball Try `setvbuf(stdin,NULL,_IONBF,0); int c; char ch; scanf("%d", &c); scanf("%c", &ch); printf("%d\n", ch);` and enter "-x". My GCC prints 45 (ASCII '-'). The first `scanf()` reads `'-'` and `'x'`, did not form an int and put them both back for the next `scanf()`. IOWs: in some select situations, a `char` may be read more than once.

Comment: @chux thanks. Unfortunately I cannot delete this answer because it's been accepted. Feel free to (heavily) edit my answer, or post your own and convince the OP to accept yours instead.

Comment: @chux , Excellent observation you got there. Should I post a new question on that?

Comment: @Cool Guy No need for a new question  (its likely to be a dupe anyways).  `scanf()` is the most complex function in C - rarely use it, preferring `fgets()` and `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc.